# Logical error I am getting unexpected result

Tags: c++, logic

I want to accept roll number , marks in 2 subjects and add the marks and display

them but the program doesn't take more than 1 students details.

this program does not take more than 40 students
I used code-blocks IDE for programming

[Please see this image for output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuPYI.jpg)

please help !!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int sum1[40];
int roll[40];
int n;
class Sb1;
class Sb2;
class Sb1
{
    public:
    float marks1[40];
    void markssb1()
    {
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
         cout<<"Enter Marks in subject 1 \n";
         cin>>marks1[40];
       }
    }
    friend void sum(Sb1,Sb2);
};
class Sb2
{
    public:
    float marks2[40];
    void markssb2()
    {
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
         cout<<"Enter Marks in subject 2 \n";
         cin>>marks2[40];
       }
    }
    friend void sum(Sb1,Sb2);
};
void sum(Sb1 obj1,Sb2 obj2)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum1[i]=obj1.marks1[i]+obj2.marks2[i];
    }
}
void display()
{
    cout<<"Serial Number\t\t\tRoll Number\t\t\tTotal Marks\n";
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<"\t\t\t\t"<<roll[i]<<"\t\t\t\t"<<sum1[i]<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Sb1 obj1;
    Sb2 obj2;
   cout<<"Enter number of students (Maximum 40 students)\n";
   cin>>n;
   if(n<=40)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Roll Number of student "<<i+1<<endl;
            cin>>roll[i];
            obj1.markssb1();
            obj2.markssb2();
            sum(obj1,obj2);
        }
        display();
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"Number of students entered exceed 40\n";
    }
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: A sum function that modifies its operand is bad design. Pass by reference and return by value.

Comment: The correct tool to diagnose such problems is a debugger, not a SO question. You should read about [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) if you are new to the world of programming.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks i am new to programming !! [link](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) its a good read thanks for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the initial mistakes I can see is this part of your code

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
     cout<<"Enter Marks in subject 1 \n";
     cin>>marks1[40];
   }
```

You're taking the input for only the 41st index every time.
Correctly it should be

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
     cout<<"Enter Marks in subject 1 \n";
     cin>>marks1[i];
   }
```

And same for the second class too.

Then there is a mistake with the second part too.

```
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Roll Number of student "<<i+1<<endl;
            cin>>roll[i];
            obj1.markssb1();
            obj2.markssb2();
            sum(obj1,obj2);
        }
    display();
```

This is taking the subject marks input for all 'n' students every time a roll no is entered.
One way of correcting the code is this -

```
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Roll Number of student "<<i+1<<endl;
            cin>>roll[i];

        }
     obj1.markssb1();
     obj2.markssb2();
     sum(obj1,obj2);
```

Comment: @GarvitKothari I've edited some more please check it out !